# Proof of Remark 6.14(b) of Milne's Arithmetic duality theorems'

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, duality, tate-shafarevich-groups

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve.Let $\operatorname{Sha}(E/\Bbb{Q})$ be a Tate-Shafarevich group.
Milne's 'Arithmetic Duality Theorems' Remark 6.14(b) describe the following exact sequence.

> Suppose $\operatorname{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is finite. Then, there is a 6-term exact
> sequence $0 \to \operatorname{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q}) \to H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}}, E) \to
>  \bigoplus_p H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}, E) \to \widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}^* \to
>  0$, where $*$ denotes the Pontryagin dual and $\widehat{E(\Bbb{Q})}$ denotes the profinite completion.

Let $\operatorname{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ be the Tate-Shafarevich group. The first 4-term sequence above is just the definition of  $\operatorname{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})$.<s>The map $\bigoplus_p H^1(G_{{\mathbb{Q}_p}}, E) \to \widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}^*$ is defined as follows</s>:(Edit:It can be defined in the case $rank(E/\Bbb{Q})=0$ and in this case $Sha(E/\Bbb{Q})$ is finite).

Fix a prime number $p$. By Tate's local duality, $H^1(G_{{\mathbb{Q}p}}, E) \cong H^0(G_{{\mathbb{Q}_p}}, E)^* = E(\mathbb{Q}_p)^*$.

Since $E(\mathbb{Q}_p) = \widehat{E(\mathbb{Q}_p)}$ and there is a natural embedding $\widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})} \to \widehat{E(\mathbb{Q}_p)}$, we obtain a surjective map $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)^* = \widehat{E(\mathbb{Q}_p)}^* \to \widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}^*$ by taking the dual of $\widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})} \to \widehat{E(\mathbb{Q}_p)}$.

Thus, there is a surjective map $\bigoplus_p H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}, E) \cong \bigoplus_p E(\mathbb{Q}_p)^* \to \widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}^*$.

The remaining task is to verify the exactness at $\bigoplus_p H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}, E)$. However, it is unclear how to use the condition that $\operatorname{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is finite.

Milne's "Arithmetic Duality Theorems" and Neukirch's "Cohomology of Number Fields" do not mention this specific aspect.

Comment: Without assuming finiteness of the Tate-Shafarevich group, the last non-zero term has to be replaced by the dual of the projective limit of $n$-Selmer groups as $n$ runs over all natural numbers. I don't think you could hope for the exactness at the term before if you have the wrong group on its right.

Comment: Also there is no reason that the map from the profinite completion of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ to the profinite completion of $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is injective. For instance if $E$ has rank $2$, then the profinite completion of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ contains two copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, while the local version is a sum os a finite group with a single copy of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Thank you very much.I was going in the wrong direction, but thanks to you, it seems I can correct my course.　Regarding this question and the comments you gave, may I ask two questions?

Comment: 1. Could you give the proof or reference for ‘Without assuming finiteness of the Tate-Shafarevich group, the last non-zero term has to be replaced by the dual of the projective limit of n-Selmer group’?

Comment: 2.When rank of $E/\Bbb{Q}$ is zero, thanks to Kolyvagin, we know that $Sha(E/\Bbb{Q})$ is finite. And there exists a natural surjective map $\bigoplus_p H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}, E) \cong \bigoplus_p E(\mathbb{Q}_p)^* \to \widehat{E(\mathbb{Q})}^*$ if I’m not mistaken. Do you think is it very possible that we can derive the result by checking the exactness at $\bigoplus_p H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}, E)$ ?

Comment: 1. This can be deduced from the 9-term Cassels-Poitou-Tate exact sequence for $n$-Selmer groups then take limits. Probably done in other places, but Coates-Sujatha's "Galois cohomology of elliptic curves" does it.
2. When the **analytic** rank is zero... $E(\mathbb{Q})\to E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is injective for any $p$ and the profinite completion doesn't do anything to it. The exactness at the local term is the hard part of the global duality statement and I don't think the additional assumption will simplify the proof. Cohomology of number fields, or the original work by Cassels are best for that

Comment: Thank you very much.  I’m reading Coates and Sujatha's 'Galois Cohomology of Elliptic Curves'. There, an exact sequence is $0 \to \text{Sel}^{p^n}(E/K) \to H^1(G_K, E[p^n]) \to \bigoplus_v H^1(G_{K_v}, E)[p^n] \to X \to 0$ ($K$: number field, $p$: prime number, n: natural number), for an appropriate finite group $X$. How can we derive the sequence $0 \to \text{Sha}(E/K) \to H^1(G_K, E) \to \bigoplus_v H^1(G_{K_v}, E) \to \widehat{E(K)}^* \to 0$ by taking limits? I’m stuck on this process because taking the limit does not seem to transition $\text{Sel}^{p^n}$ to $\text{Sha}$.